# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' for csv dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file that looks something like this:

```
criteria1,criteria2,criteria3
5,3,4
3,5,2
```

I want to apply an average weighting function using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

#read the csv file
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

#define weights
weights = [0.3, 0.4, 0.3]

#calculate average weighting
df['average_weighting'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x[0]*weights[0] + x[1]*weights[1] + x[2]*weights[2]) / sum(weights), axis=1)
```

---

while executing the line calculate the average weighting line-
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

I want a solution for the Typeerror.

Comment: what is `df['average_weighting'].dtype` ?

Comment: Post whole error message with traceback. Do not truncate error messages.

Answer (score 0):

It is indicating that you are attempting to add a string and int variable together. To solve that you just need to cast the string to an int or the int to a string, depending on what type of adding you are looking for. Also important to note is that Python supports string multiplication, which is why string * int doesn't throw an error.

In this case, its likely that one or more of your x values are coming in as a string. Doing something like this should solve this particular TypeError.

```
df['average_weighting'] = df.apply(lambda x: (int(x[0])*weights[0] + int(x[1])*weights[1] + int(x[2])*weights[2]) / sum(weights), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, but after executing this line I got this error from my code-invalid literal for int() with base 10

Comment: You may then want to check the output of your df. since that is the error which comes from trying to typecast a string to an int that isn't a number. For example, if you do int("a") it will throw that error. You would want to check to see if the values you are applying on are numeric in nature. If only some of them are, you will want to reconsider how you applying your weighted average across the values.

Comment: Another thing to note is what type of values you are expecting. If, for example, you are expecting x[0] to be a decimal, instead of an int(x[0]) you would do float(x[0]). This won't be the cause of the invalid literal for int() with base 10 error, but it can lead to value truncation that leads to the values that you want being wrong.

Comment: Code executed successfully!! Thank you Once again.

Answer (score 0):

It shows that your data collected from the csv file has string type and you are adding strings with integers(weights). So as @Shorn's indicate you should convert the csv data to integer first.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like values in the data frame are being treated like strings so try converting values into int or float.

You can try this df = df.astype(float)